# Calculating numpy.mean with array?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I'm trying define a procedure that calculates mean of daily returns for every security:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def security_mean(com):
    CSV = csv.reader(open("my_file.csv","rb"))
    foo = False
    old = 0
    new = 0
    mean = []
    for row in CSV:
        try:
            if foo == True:
                old = float(row[-1])
                x = (new - old) / old
                mean.append(x)
                new = float(row[-1])
                foo = True
            else:
                new = float(row[-1])
                foo = True
        except ValueError:
            string = row[-1]
            continue
    value = np.mean(mean)
    print string + ' mean: ' + str(value)
```

Here is `my_file.csv`:

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close           Volume    Adj Close
2013-09-27  874.82  877.52  871.31  876.39  1258800    876.39
2013-09-26  878.3   882.75  875 878.17  1259900        878.17
2013-09-25  886.55  886.55  875.6   877.23  1649000    877.23
2013-09-24  886.5   890.1   881.4   886.84  1467000    886.84
2013-09-23  896.15  901.59  885.2   886.5   1777400    886.5
2013-09-20  898.39  904.13  895.62  903.11  4345300    903.11
2013-09-19  905.99  905.99  895.4   898.39  1597900    898.39
2013-09-18  886.35  903.97  883.07  903.32  1934700    903.32
2013-09-17  887.41  888.39  881 886.11  1259400        886.11
2013-09-16  896.2   897 884.87  887.76  1336500        887.76
```

Can I make my function smaller using array? How?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** daily return formula: **(x - y)/y** or  **(x / y) - 1** ; where x = today Adj close, and y = yesterday Adj close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the close values into a vector, say adj_close, you can write new - old was a vector, adj_close[1:] - adj_close[:-1].

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def security_mean(com):
    CSV = csv.reader(open("my_file.csv","rb"))
    CSV.next() # skip header row
    adj_close = np.array([row[-1] for  row in CSV], dtype=np.float32)
    value = np.mean( (adj_close[1:] / adj_close[:-1] - 1. )
    print string + ' mean: ' + str(value)
```

Comment: it returns me an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: new error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: Adj Close

Comment: OK.  That's the header line.  I need to skip a row.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can simplify your function using `np.loadtxt()`:

```
np.loadtxt('my_file.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6)).mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: @MichaelVayvala this would occur if some index in `usecols` is higher than `number of columns-1`